# Omitting article before "evaluation"

Tags: word-usage, articles

In the sentence

> This talk focuses on an evaluation of....

it somehow feels way more natural to omit the article:

> This talk focuses on evaluation of....

Or at least change the sentence like so:

> The focus of this talk is an evaluation of....

Is my gut feeling correct? If so, why?

Answer (score 3):

The first sentence

> This talk focuses on an evaluation of....

means the talk is *about* a **particular** evaluation that has been made.

The second sentence

> This talk focuses on evaluation of....

means the talk is *about* the **process** of evaluating....

The third sentence

> The focus of this talk is an evaluation of....

means that the *talk itself* is making an evaluation of something.

and so I would say both the second and third sentences change the original meaning.

Comment: I agree with this. Although I would add that the second sentence doesn't sound normal to me. If dropping the article, I would make another change: *This talk focuses on* ***evaluating*** *[something].*